GRX disc brake caliper confusion
Trying to sort a rubbing issue and keep reading things like "push BOTH pistons back in, squeeze lever to center pistonS" but it looks to me like there is only one piston? When I squeeze the lever with the pads remove I just see one coming out from the left, the other side just looks like a hole. Is that right?
Photo: https://i.postimg.cc/dV4LGGrZ/IMG20240707202807.jpg

Hi, welcome to bicycles.  It might help if you told us the year or model number of your brakes, in case there have been changes over time.  It would definitely help us if you took some photos and [edit]ed them into your question.

That’s not right. There are two pistons and two pads in a GRX caliper. Did you ever (repeatedly) squeeze the lever with out a disc in the caliper?

Added a photo but it's waiting for approval

https://i.postimg.cc/dV4LGGrZ/IMG20240707202807.jpg

@Omiron Are you the one who posted the question?  If so please merge your accounts.  If not, how can you be sure you're looking at the same thing OP is?

@DavidW yes I'm OP I asked as guest but now it's picked up the account i use in other stack communities
